# connect MongoDB and Solr 8.2 using DataImportHandler

Tags: mongodb, solr, dataimporthandler

I am trying to import mongoDB data for search using solr. I went through many documents but confused as I can see many solrconfig.xml file and one that present in _default (is the one I am using) even after updating as documented. in solr UI "files" section the changes does not reflect( started solr). also, dataimport screen still shows "The solrconfig.xml file for this index does not have an operational DataImportHandler defined!" and not found any error in logs as well.

Comment: Integrating MongoDB and Solr is usually done through [mongo-connector](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector). What configuration have you done to use the DataImportHandler?

Comment: Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to load EntityProcessor implementation for entity:sample_entity Processing Document # 1
 at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:271)

Comment: That's the error message, not the configuration. If you're going to use DIH to integrate with Mongo, you'll have to say how you've attempted to do that, since most people use `mongo-connector` to do that (as it gives you close to real time updates and doesn't have to handle imports by themselves)

Comment: Thank you , I was configuring in wrong xml file. Solved the issue.

Comment: You should add an answer about which XML-file you were editing and which one you should have been editing to help future readers of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:
I was modifying solrconfix.xml in generic places (there are 7-8 files with same name). I have modified the one in my core. Aslo I added db-connection.xml at same directory. No need to write schema.xml any more as schema-configuration file is present.